# how to extract the properties from a neo4j cypher collection from the query result

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j Cypher query where I return the result as a COLLECTION like this:

```
RETURN COLLECT(r) AS Shipper
```

now I try to use

```
shippers  = result.records[0].get('Shipper').properties;
```

but I get undefined value for shippers. I cannot seem to locate in the docs how to retrieve the properties from a COLLECTION. The raw collection data looks like this:

```
[{"identity":{"low":1112,"high":0},"start":{"low":320,"high":0},"end":{"low":447,"high":0},"type":"SHIPPED_WITH","properties":{"name":"DHL","account":"483097049790yrh"}},{"identity":{"low":1111,"high":0},"start":{"low":320,"high":0},"end":{"low":442,"high":0},"type":"SHIPPED_WITH","properties":{"name":"UPS","account":"12345T6741"}}]
```

I know I can avoid using the collection and retrieve the data in loop of some sort but I figure there is a better way. I am expecting to get an array of objects. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to retrieve properties from a set of relationships, you could do this:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE   // your WHERE clause

// return a list of maps with keys `id` and `properties`
RETURN {id:id(r),properties:properties(r)}) AS Shipper
```

OR

```
// return just the properties as a map
RETURN properties(r) AS propertiesMap
```

OR

```
// return a collection of maps
RETURN COLLECT(properties(r)) AS listOfPropertyMaps
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I forgot to mentioned that I am using Neo4j 3.5.3. I am not seeing any docs on this...also I assume the missing '}' is a typo. Can you elaborate on this answer including how you would retrieve the properties.

Comment: @MichaelE there was indeed a typo. I corrected it and added more RETURN statements that allow you to retrieve the properties.